# how to validate 2-way SSL certificates?

Tags: security, http, ssl, tcp, openssl

I need to validate client as well as server's certificate.How can I do it at TCP level and at HTTP level? for Http I use cURL client library.OpenSSL is the SSL library.This has to be done through self signed certificates only.Which web server or http server I need to use which validates client's SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using self-signed certificates, you can configure that certificate as though it were the one and only authorized CA. If the peer presents that very certificate, it will be accepted because it appears in the list of CAs. If the peer presents any other certificate (or no certificate), it should be rejected.

You didn't say what programming language you are using with libcurl, but here's a pyCurl example for verifying the server:

```
req.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
req.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, "/the/path/to/the/certificate/we/want/the/peer/to/use")
```

and of course the client wants to authenticate itself to the server:

```
req.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, "/the/certificate/the/client/will/present")
req.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEY, "/the/private/key/that/goes/with/it/in/PEM/format")
```

As for the server side, it's generally easy to configure as well, but it depends what web server software you're using.

**EDIT**: Elaboration as requested on "you can configure that certificate as though it were the one and only authorised CA".

Normally, a peer presents a certificate, and the local end validates it against a CA (or a list of CAs). The CA is a *different* certificate than the peer's certificate. The CA certificate has either directly or indirectly signed the peer's certificate.

When using a self-signed certificate, then the peer can present that certificate. The local end can pretend that the same certificate is a CA certificate. Because the certificate is signed by itself (by definition), it qualifies in this case as being signed by a valid CA... since a valid CA is itself!.

Comment: I'm more interested in this statement "you can configure that certificate as though it were the one and only authorised CA".Can you please elaborate? btw, I'm using c as a prog language with libcurl.

Comment: So, you mean to say, if I add the CA(which is also a self signed one) certified server certificate to apache or some web server and the self signed CA certificate to the client PC's certificate bundle,it should work? is it so?

Comment: Yes, that will work, but it will be too permissive. Don't *add* it to the list of CAs (certificate bundle). You should *set* the list of CAs to contain that certificate and that certificate alone. Otherwise the authentication would pass if the peer presents some other certificate signed by some other CA (because that CA is in the bundle). You only want the authenticatio to pass if the peer uses the specific self-signed certificate you're insterested in.

Comment: And, do I need to add the same CA cert to the web server's conf path?

Comment: I could able to successfully connect to https://localhost. But my firefox browser throws an error code: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert even when I added the ca.crt to the Trusted Root CA certificates.Though it's not my concern now! Thanks @Celada